# LaTeX document and BoundingBox of an eps file created by matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, latex, eps

I am having a problem in including an eps file generated by matplotlib into a LaTeX document. The size of the figure does not seems to be recognized correctly, and the caption overlaps with the figure.

Please see the image below. This is the image of the latex document which includes figures generated by matplotlib. The LaTeX source file and the python source code for the plotting are shown further below.

========================

[image: Image of the LaTeX document.]

=======================

Figure 1. is overlapped by the caption. It seems that the LaTeX recognizes the figure to have a smaller size than the actual size.

Figure 2. is the same eps file as Figure 1., but the `bb` parameters were specified in `includegraphics` command in the LaTeX document. The BoundingBox of the eps file is `%%BoundingBox: 18 180 594 612`, and the `bb` parameters were set as `bb=0 0 594 612`. The first two values are changed to zero while the last two values are kept. Then, Figure 2. looks good. The size of the figure seems to be recognized correctly.

I did not have this type of problem in other computers so far, and I wonder what is causing the problem. I am not sure if is the problem of matplotlib or LaTex, and I would like to have suggestions about how to find the source of the problem.

The version of matplotlib package is 1.1.1rc, and OS is Ubuntu 12.04. I processed the LaTeX document by `latex` command and then `dvipdfm` command.

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.1.1rc'

$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.16; using libpng 1.5.16
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03


$ dvipdfm --version

This is dvipdfmx-20130405 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
modified for TeX Live,
an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

Copyright (C) 2002-2013 by the DVIPDFMx project team

This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.
```

Here is the LaTeX source file.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}



\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph of the text.
Today is a good day. 

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{fig.eps}
\caption{This is the caption of the figure included without specifying bb parameters.}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

This is the second paragraph of the text written below the first figure environment.
Tomorrow will be a bad day.

\begin{figure}[hb]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 594 612, width=.5\linewidth]{fig.eps}
\caption{This is the caption of the figure included with the first two bb parameters set zero.}
\label{fig2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

% Note that fig.eps has the following bounding box information.
% $ grep BoundingBox fig.eps 
% %%BoundingBox: 18 180 594 612


\end{document}
```

Here is the python source code used for plotting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], '-b')
plt.savefig('fig.eps')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example and it worked with `dvips` instead . Afterwards a `ps2pdf` does the job. So maybe `dvipdfm` does something wrong with the bounding box.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The combination of `dvips` and `ps2pdf` worked also for me. In fact, I realized that the dvi file looks correct. (I used `evince` to see the dvi and pdf files.) It is great that you identified that `dvipdfm` is the problem.

Comment: I tried replacing `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}` in the LaTeX document to `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx,color}` and processing it by `latex` and `dvipdfm`. Then, the resulted pdf file looks correct. I did not have a problem with the `dvips` option on other systems, and I still do not understand the mechanism of the problem. I would be glad to hear someone's explanations even though the solutions are found.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should set the figure dimensions using the `plt.figure()` function with the `figsize=(x,y)` option. You should also set the bounding box in the `plt.savefig()` function with the `bbox_inches='tight'` option, which should remove the extra whitespace around your figure.

Some other things you can try include setting the backend to 'PS' if you haven't already using:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('PS')
```

Additionally, I use the `format='eps'` option in my savefig function, though it shouldn't be necessary since you already have the eps extension on your filename, but it doesn't hurt to give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I initially used the `figsize` parameter and `bbox_inches='tight'`, but I had the same problem. I tried to minimize the script as posted in the original question.

Comment: I updated my answer, which includes the only options that I use that should control the figure output, and I am having no problems with the bounding box in my eps files. When you convert your eps to pdf does it result in a similar problem, or is the bounding box correct?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried `mpl.use('PS')` as you suggested, and I also tried adding `format='eps'` in savefig function, but neither trial worked unfortunately. The 'fig.eps' file and a pdf file generated by `epspdf fig.eps` both look correct in both cases where `mpl.use('PS')` is used and where the plotting script in the original question is used. It seems that the eps file generated by matplotlib has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using OSX, the following command might help:

$gs -o temp.ps -sDEVICE=ps2write -dEPSCrop matplotlib.eps

$ps2eps temp.ps

Related reference : http://syatsin.blogspot.jp/2016/09/how-to-solve-bounding-box-problem-with.html